# How to write code that logs each letter of the message using the map in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

ex.

```
var myMessage = "coding is really fun" 
let newMessage = myMessage.map(??)
console.log(newMessage)
```

I'm new to coding and having a hard time with this equation.

Comment: You cannot use `.map` on a string in JavaScript. You have to convert it to an array...but at that point you'll have separate characters. I'm not sure how you can use `.map` in this case.

Comment: Each letter or each character? `map` is an array method, not a string method. I’d use `.forEach(console.log)` on a character array. `map` isn’t the right tool here.

Comment: For the question It gives a string. I guess I don't know how to convert it to an array then use maps to log each individual character. My simple plan of attack was:                                     var myMessage = "coding is really fun"
let newMessage = myMessage.split("")
console.log(newMessage)

Comment: @stephen1993 You’re almost there. Answer for yourself: what does the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Return_value) method return? Could one use the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method on this return value?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
const myMessage = "coding is really fun".split('')
    .map(letter => console.log(letter));
```

Comment: Do not use `.map` for a simple iteration. Either return something from the callback or use `.forEach`.

Comment: Yeah, but it looks like @stephen1993 wants to practice with `map`, at least this is what assumed from the question asked. In case he doesn't want to store the values in an array, no need to use `map`

Comment: @OriolGrau thank you this is what I was looking for. In my problem I had to use .map even though it wasn't the best way of turning a string into individual characters. Can you explain what is going on on the second line. Are you making 'letter' a function then calling that function? Is there a simpler way of writing that last line so I can see in a step by step process.

Comment: `split` tansforms the string in an array of letters, and `map` iterates on each letter. `letter` there represents each one of the items in the array, you can change the name to whatever you think fits best

Comment: One thing I like to do when learning is break everything in small chunks and `console.log` everything to be able to follow exactly what is going on in every step.

Comment: Thanks! I have just never seen the console.log on the inside of brackets, its always in the beginning. You really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of using `.map` method is to convert a string to an array.

```
var myMessage = 'coding is really fun';
var newMessage = Array.from(myMessage).map(function(letter) {
    console.log(letter);
});
```

`Array.from(myMessage)` method will transform string `myMessage` to an array, so after that you'll be able to use `.map` method on it.

P. S.: NOTE, that using `.map` method and not returning anything is a BAD practice. If you don't return anything, then use `.forEach` method.

**EDIT:** As @Ivar correctly noted, there's no any sense to save the outcome of `.map` in a variable, if we, in this particular case, don't return anything from it. So, the second line can be just:

```
Array.from(myMessage).map(function(letter) {
    console.log(letter);
}
```

Comment: Do not use `.map` for a simple iteration. Either return something from the callback or use `.forEach`.

Comment: Thank you, @VLAZ, I've seen your comment on the previous answer. My answer is just another way of attempting to attach .map to a String.

Comment: And that's still a bad practice.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to assign the outcome of `map` back to `newMessage` if you don't `return` anything inside the callback. `newMessage` will always be an array of `undefined` values.